# By changing the value on a cell, the colour within a shape automatically changes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA but have some basic understanding of code writing plus also looking on various youtube videos. courses etc on writing macros in VBA. This is what I want to do but after a number of attempts and hours of research and effort, I'm making no progress.

I doing basic sports stats for matchday for a local club where we have two teams playing. I've created a simple front end where I have 11 buttons (shapes) with a player number on each square for Team A and then another set of 11 buttons for Team B with players number on those squares. So if Player 5 scores a goal for Team A, I click on the square with "2" under Team A and if Player 7 scores a goal for Team B, then I click on Square labelled 7 on Team B.So in total, I have 22 buttons..

## Here what I like to do.

If Team A is the Red Bull's for example and I know they wear Red Red Jerseys, I like the buttons for Team A to go Red automatically. If team B is the Blue Angels for example and wear Blue jerseys, then I like Team B buttons to go Blue automatically. If I changed Team A from Red Bull to Blue Angel's, then I like the Buttons on Team A to auto change from Red to Blue if you follow me.

Sorry if I made this explanation more complicated then necessary and for the silly team names but hoping, it gives you are the idea of what I'm trying to achieve..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO Jhon, what have you tried so far? Edit your question with the code you've tried and if possible some screenshots of your sheets and the desired output.

Comment: You would need one cell with a drop down list of possible team colours/names for both the Home and Away sides.

Then you can link all your Home Player Buttons to the Home Team Name and similar for the away. Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quick quickly ..

Comment: I’ve included a screenshot of the front-end menu I’m using which believe it or not works pretty well with a mixture of some VBA code and Excel formulas.
I want these buttons to change colour depending on the name of the team.
I tried over and over writing VBA code based on instinct or cut and paste for google searches but the best I could find is as below which I know is pretty useless. So hoping to can steer me in the right direction or at least give me basic code pieces I need to make some progress as I’m lost at this moment.

Comment: Cut and pasted code..
Sub Worksheet_colour(ByVal Target As Range)
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
    If UCase(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1)) = "Team A" Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
    End If
    If UCase(ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value) = "Team B" Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
    End If
    If UCase(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1)) = "Team C" Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlue
    End IF
End Sub

Thanks in advance  John

Comment: sorry but how do I add a screenshot to this comment ?

Comment: Resolved the problem as modified an existing code....cheers